# How to transfer media files from an SSD with a bad OS on it (MacBook Pro)

Tags: mac, macbook-pro, hard-drive-recovery

Recently my MacBook Pro (2010 15") took a dookie. I took it to Fry's (with a few upgrades I have bought for it) and they told me that since the OS is bad on my old SSD, they can't clone the contents of the old drive onto my new drive.

They, however, said they could transfer all files (and not apps). Since they wanted 70 bucks for that, I wanted to see if it's an easy/ straightforward process I can do myself.

I assume I have to plug in the SSD into the computer for starters. The SSD itself has no port, so I assume I need some sort of an extension for this. Here's a picture of it, in case that's helpful:
[image]
I would be extremely grateful for some useful links.

Comment: You would need a USB adapter. A good quality one isn't much cheaper than the store's fee. But if you have a desktop computer with a free SATA connector and Linux then you may have a chance of reading the drive without additional parts.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily connect it to your Mac via a "USB to SATA Adapter Cable," which you can get pretty inexpensively via Amazon. I've had great luck with both [StarTech](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=usb%20to%20sata%20startech&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Ausb%20to%20sata%20startech) and [IO Crest](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=usb%20to%20sata%20io%20crest) brands.

Once plugged into your new machine, the SSD may not mount. First check and see whether Disk Utility sees it. If not, you may need to opt for a commercial tool like [Disk Drill](https://www.cleverfiles.com/), which you can try out for free and pay only if it finds files you want to restore, or the like. I've also had luck with [Disk Warrior](https://www.alsoft.com/DiskWarrior/).

Once you get your files on the new drive, start backing up either via [Time Machine](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201250) on a new drive or online via something like [BackBlaze](https://www.backblaze.com/). Ideally, do both.

Note: I have no financial interest in any company I mentioned. I've just found them to be reliable solutions.